# Can I filter entityFieldQuery results by Workbench moderation state?

Tags: entities

I have the Workbench module and I want to look up nodes which have a specific workbench state with EntityFieldQuery.

I can get articles assigned to a user as follows:

```
$articles = new EntityFieldQuery();
$articles->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
         ->fieldCondition('field_moderating_user', 'uid', $user_id, '=');
```

Now I want to add a condition that only gets articles that have the state 'assigned'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An EntityFieldQuery can only filter based on fields associated with the entity by default, and since workbench moderation records are held in a custom table outside of the field system the standard query can't include a reference to them.

However, you can extend the query using tags and [`hook_query_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7), e.g.:

```
function MYMODULE_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  // Only change the query if we have the required tag
  if ($query->hasTag('WorkbenchModerationAssigned')) {
    // Join the workbench moderation node history table
    $query->join('workbench_moderation_node_history', 'wmnh', 'wmnh.nid = n.nid');

    // Add the state and current conditions
    $query->condition('wmnh.state', 'assigned');
    $query->condition('wmnh.current', 1);
  }
}
```

You would then build up your EntityFieldQuery like this:

```
$articles = new EntityFieldQuery();
$articles->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->fieldCondition('field_moderating_user', 'uid', $user_id, '=')
  ->addTag('WorkbenchModerationAssigned');
```

That's a very basic example which may need some changing, you might also want to join in the `workbench_moderation_states` table but it depends on your exact requirements.

**EDIT**

Just for a bit more info you can also use [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7) to do this in a more targeted manner:

```
function MYMODULE_query_WorkbenchModerationAssigned_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->join('workbench_moderation_node_history', 'wmnh', 'wmnh.nid = n.nid');
  // ...
```

Comment: Just 2 changes:
n.nid will be node.nid and
wmnh.current will be wmnh.is_current